# Develop a Server-sent events by next.js, it works on my local, but doesn't on vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

Example is very simple as below. First, create a new Next.js app by running the following command in your terminal, and update like this.
Server

```
export default (req, res) => {
  // Set headers to allow SSE
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream')
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive')
  res.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "none");

  // Send an initial "ping" message
  res.write('data: ping\n\n')

  // Set up an interval to send messages every 5 seconds
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    res.write('data: message\n\n')
  }, 5000)

  // Set up a listener for when the client closes the connection
  res.on('close', () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId)
    res.end()
  })
}
```

Client

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [source, setSource] = useState(null)

  const handleStart = () => {
    const newSource = new EventSource('/api/sse')
    newSource.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log('Received message:', event.data)
    }
    setSource(newSource)
  }

  const handleStop = () => {
    if (source) {
      source.close()
      setSource(null)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

when it's deployed on vercel, only `res.end()` called, then the `onmessage` will be triggered.
https://github.com/CPPAlien/test-sse

https://test-sse.vercel.app/

Answer (score -2):

also running into same issue on nextJS v13 dev / i think its something related to actual nextJS configuration, as I then also tried to deploy on another service (netlify) and get the same issue